# Using Recursive Query Using CTE

Tags: sql-server, hierarchical-data

I'm trying to write an efficient recursive query. I've run across CTEs and have found a number of examples. However, every example I've found is returning the same data that is recursive where I need to return some different data.

For example, my hierarchical data is a table of Locations.

```
[Locations]
ID int
Title nvarchar(100)
ParentLocationID int
```

But the data I want to return is in a table of Activities. I want to return all activities associated with a particular location, and all "child" locations.

```
[Activities]
ID int
Title nvarchar(100)
LocationID int
```

I'm new to CTEs and can't quite see how to do this from the examples I have. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the recursive CTE to find all locations in the hierarchy then join the `Activities` table onto the result of that.

```
;WITH R
     AS (SELECT ID,
                Title,
                ParentLocationID
         FROM   [Locations]
         WHERE  ID = @LocationId
         UNION ALL
         SELECT L.ID,
                L.Title,
                L.ParentLocationID
         FROM   [Locations] L
                JOIN R
                  ON L.ParentLocationID = R.ID)
SELECT * /*TODO: Select columns of interest*/
FROM   R
       JOIN [Activities] A
         ON A.LocationID = R.ID
```

Comment: I see now. You are just doing what the examples I've seen were doing, and then selecting related rows by doing a join on the results. Thanks!